# Lorem ipsum of Perl, C#, C, Java?

Tags: testing, testcase

In visually testing interfaces where code might live what do you use for your particular language for a standard?  "Hello World" is not sufficiently complex enough in most cases.  I am particularly interested in Perl but C#, C, C++, and Java are coming up.

Per the comment:

Lets say you created a new IDE, color scheme, or a web page where code will be placed by you or others.  You want to see what your changes look like with stuff that looks like with typical code.  [Lorem Ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) is used by type setting programs but it isn't really code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You might want to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a code sample for each such language you're interested in, and have it in a file.

e.g. `sample.c`, `sample.py`, `sample.java`, etc.

[Editra](http://editra.org/) uses such files to test syntax coloring and stuff.

http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxPython/3rdParty/Editra/tests/syntax/

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably open up one (well, a few) of my code files. Because they contain the sort of code I work with on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a hard time fitting what you are after all on one page.  You should make sure to utilize all keywords.  Check out the [Perltidy Style Key](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/stylekey.html), as that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

a quick wikipedia search of "<name of prog language> keywords" will give a nice article for most that contains the keywords.

things you can test (top of my head):

arithmetic operators

object creation and deletion (if supported)

declaration of types

importing external libraries or functions